# Как в Laravel 8 сделать поиск по псевдонимам столбцов?

Tags: laravel, join

Не понимаю, как организовать в `Laravel` поиск по псевдонимам столбцов. Джойню таблицы, в которых присутствуют колонки с одинаковыми названиями. Каждой присваиваю свой псевдоним. И если в `where()` использую псевдонимы, то вижу ошибку. Получается, псевдонимы в `select()` вообще не работают?

**БД**:

```
class
id | name

student
id | name | class_id
```

**Код**:

```
$name = 'Иван'
$column = 'student_name' //выдаёт ошибку
//$column = 's.name'     //не выдаёт ошибку
$data = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('student AS s')
    ->leftJoin('class AS c', 'c.id', 's.class_id')
    ->select('s.name AS student_name', 'c.name AS class_title')
    ->where($column, '=', $name)
    ->get()->toArray();
```

**Ошибка**:

> ```
> Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "student_name" does not exist
> ```

**Laravel 8, база Постгресс**.

Comment: Алиасы можно использовать, напр., с having.. у WHERE надо указывать именно колонку с базы

Comment: Ну.... Насколько помню вам нужен сырой запрос для того чт обы задать алиас и тогда он будет доступен в where

Comment: `selectRaw('s.name AS student_name, c.name AS class_title')`